# (My)SQL multiple in-depth left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can anybody please show me how to make a view as multiple left join?

```
A GAME has zero or multiple LINKs (OneToMany on GAME.ID = LINK.GAME_ID)
Each LINK has exactly one of multiple STOREs (OneToOne on LINK.STORE_ID = STORE.ID)
Each STORE has exactly one of multiple PLATFORMs (OneToOne on STORE.PLATFORM_ID = PLATFORM.ID)
```

And I want to make a VIEW as

```
PLATFORM_ID (FK)    GAME_ID (FK)
--------------------------------
```

I mean I want to list `GAME`s, by the given `PLATFORM`, which each has **at least** one or more paths through `LINK` and `STORE` to the `PLATFORM`

Thank you.

Comment: If your game table already includes `STORE_ID`, why do you need `link` as an in between table?

Comment: For guys who answered: Thank you guys. Let me please take some time to check every answers. Sorry I wouldn't asked if I could even know any suggested answer is right or not.

Comment: @Andomar I'm sorry for confusion. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.PLATFORM_ID, l.GAME_ID
FROM Games g 
LEFT JOIN Links l ON g.ID = l.GAME_ID
INNER JOIN Stores ON l.STORE_ID = s.STORE_ID
INNER JOIN PLATFORMS p ON s.PLATFORM_ID = p.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
   l.game_id, p.platform_id
from
   links l,
   stores s,
   platforms p
where
   l.link_id = s.link_id
and
   p.platform_id = s.platform_id
group by 
   l.game_id, p.platform_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL will be,

```
select GAME_ID 
from GAME,STORE,PLATFORM
where 
PLATFORM.ID = STORE.PLATFORM_ID
and STORE.ID = GAME.STORE_ID
and PLATFORM.ID = {some_ID}
```

Comment: Thank you @UmeshA. For readers, this answers is written before I corrected my own confusing description.